# How to add dynamiclly logo in wordpress theme?

Tags: logo

I am making a theme. I can insert logo by editing in header file but how it can be dynamiccaly from wordpress dashboard

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do a "Theme Options" section. It's not so simple to do imo and it is very widely procedure so I recommend Codex lecture.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to spend a little cash, you can do it by using "Advanced Customs Fields Options". They even include a video tutorial on how to use it.

You can follow this link to learn more: [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/)